# Given that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi m}{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}$ prove $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, rational-numbers

Given that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi m}{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}, \, n \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}.$

I know nothing about how to attack the problem. I believe I need to suppose that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\right) \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ and somehow show that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi m}{n}\right) \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ what would have been a contradiction. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: What theorems do you know about integers satisfying $\gcd(m,n)=1$ ?

Comment: Hint: For $m=3, n=7$, we have that $\cos \left(5 \cdot \frac{6 \pi}{7}\right) = \cos \frac{30 \pi}{7} = \cos\left(4\pi + \frac{2\pi}{7}\right) = \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$. But where did I get that $5$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

- For all $\theta\in\mathbb R, m\in\mathbb N$, $\cos(m\theta)$ can be expressed as a polynomial of $\cos(\theta)$ (with rational coefficients), so if $\cos(\theta)$ is rational, so is $\cos(m\theta)$.
- If $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there exists $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $mk\equiv 1 \bmod  n$.
- The cosine function is periodic modulo $2\pi$, that is, $\cos(\theta + 2\pi) = \cos(\theta)$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb R$.

Can you combine these facts to come up with a proof of the desired result?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't link these. In particular I don't understand how to use the second one. I know that $mk \equiv 1 \mod n \iff \exists d \in \mathbb{N}: mk - nd = 1$

Comment: @ioleg19029700 what if I told you that $\cos(k\cdot 2\pi m/n) = \cos(2\pi/n)$?

Comment: I think you should emphasize that the polynomial have integer coefficients, otherwise would be hard to imagine how to use the hint.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, good point. Make that *rational* coefficients (they do have integer coefficients, but rational is all we need).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it still. I tried several times to follow your hints step by step, but I just can't formulate it in a kind of "story" if you will. So let $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}$, then $\cos(m\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^p a_i\cos^i(\theta)$

Comment: I think I got it. As $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \,\, s.t. mx + ny = 1$. Now lets divide both sides by n, we get $\frac{mx}{n} + y = \frac{1}{n}$ and now let's multiply both sides by $2\pi \ \Rightarrow x\frac{2\pi m}{n} + (2\pi)y = \frac{2\pi}{n}$. And as $\cos(\theta)$ is periodic modulo $2\pi$ we can switch $\cos(m\theta)$ in LHS with $\cos(\theta)$ is RHS which would let to $\cos(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^p a_i\cos^i(m\theta), a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. As power of rational is rational and sum of rational numbers is rational Q.E.D.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer, is my previous comment correct?

Comment: @ioleg19029700 Yep, that works! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. You know that $\Re(\zeta^m)\in\mathbb Q$ and you want to show that $\Re(\zeta)\in\mathbb Q$. Since $m$ and $n$ are coprime $\zeta^m$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity as well. This implies that we have $(\zeta^m)^k=\zeta$ for a $k\in\mathbb N$.

So it is enough (even better) to prove that for a number $\zeta \in \mathbb C$ with $|\zeta|=1$ and $\Re(\zeta) \in \mathbb Q$ you have $\Re(\zeta^n) \in \mathbb Q$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

We have
$$\zeta^n=(x+iy)^n  = \sum_{k=0}^n  {{n}\choose{k}} x^k (iy)^k $$
The real part of this is given by only giving a shit on the even $k$. But then we have an even power of $y$ and we have $y^2=1-x^2 \in \mathbb Q$, so everything is in $\mathbb Q$.